# Filter todo items in vanilla javascript todo list

Tags: javascript, html-select

I'm building a todo list and now I'm stuck on trying to implement a HTML-select dropdown to filter between the completed and uncompleted todo items.
I'm using switch statements to select the respective blocks to be executed however I keep getting the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" but I don't understand what element is undefined.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const addTodoButton = document.getElementById('addTodoButton')
const todoUL = document.getElementById('todoUL')
const filterOptions = document.querySelector('.filter-todos')

addTodoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo)
todoUL.addEventListener('click', remove);
filterOptions.addEventListener('click', filterTodos);

// Add todo
function addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoText = input.value
    const todoEl = `<li><span>${todoText}</span> <button class="delete" id="deleteTodoButton"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Delete</button> <button class="complete" id="completeTodoButton"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Completed</button></li>`
    input.value = ""
    input.focus()

    if (!todoText) {
        alert('You must type a todo')
    } else {
        todoUL.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", todoEl)
    }
}

// Remove/Complete todo
function remove(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'deleteTodoButton') {
        e.target.parentElement.remove()
        input.focus()
    } else {
        e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('completed')
        input.focus()
    }
}

function filterTodos(e) {
    const todos = todoUL.childNodes
    todos.forEach(function (todoEl) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todoEl.style.display = "flex"
                break;

            case "completed":
                if (todoEl.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    todoEl.style.display = "flex"
                } else {
                    todoEl.style.display = "none"
                }
                break;
        }
    })
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>Todo List App</h1>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your todo">
      <button type="submit" class="add-todo" id="addTodoButton">Add</button>
      <select name="todos" class="filter-todos">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoUL">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: `const todos = todoUL.childNodes` change to `const todos = [...todoUL.children]` .... childNodes includes `#text` nodes that don't have `style` ... unfortunately ....children is a HTMLCollection which does not have a forEach method, unlike `childNodes` which is a NodeList with a forEach method ... hence the `[... ]` business

Comment: alternatively you can check in your forEach that the `.nodeName` is not `#text` or `#comment` ... easier to add `if (todoEl.nodeName[0] != '#')` before the `switch` - this will work in older browsers too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made this working in my on way of interpretation. Hope this will help you in some ways.

I had identified some issues with the code you have written

First thing the `click` event to the select should be changed to `change` event

Second in case of `remove` function, you have to check the `e.target.id == "completeTodoButton"` before marking it completed, else our node selection wont work.

Third, in case of `filterTodos` function you have to ensure the node type is `li` before toggling the display. I used `todoEl.nodeName === "LI"` comparison for this.

Inside the switch case, you cannot use `todoEl.classList.contains("completed")` because the completed class is not bibded to `li` instead it in bonded to the `span` tag inside the `li`. You could either move this the class to `li` node and stle the elements accordingly or if you want to continue with the current structure you should use `todoEl.children[0].classList.contains("completed")` because the first child node of the `li` is the span with class `completed`.

Also you missed the case `uncompleted` in the switch.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>Todo List App</h1>
    <form id="form">
    <input
        type="text"
        id="input"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Enter your todo"
    />
    <button type="submit" class="add-todo" id="addTodoButton">Add</button>
    <select name="todos" class="filter-todos">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
    </select>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoUL"></ul>
</div>

<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("input");
    const addTodoButton = document.getElementById("addTodoButton");
    const todoUL = document.getElementById("todoUL");
    const filterOptions = document.querySelector(".filter-todos");

    addTodoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
    todoUL.addEventListener("click", remove);
    filterOptions.addEventListener("change", filterTodos);

    // Add todo
    function addTodo(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const todoText = input.value;
      const todoEl = `<li><span>${todoText}</span>
        <button class="delete" id="deleteTodoButton"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Delete</button>
        <button class="complete" id="completeTodoButton"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Completed</button></li>`;
      input.value = "";
      input.focus();

      if (!todoText) {
        alert("You must type a todo");
      } else {
        todoUL.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", todoEl);
      }
    }

    // Remove/Complete todo
    function remove(e) {
      if (e.target.id == "deleteTodoButton") {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        input.focus();
      } else if (e.target.id == "completeTodoButton") {
        e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle(
          "completed"
        );
        input.focus();
      }
    }

    function filterTodos(e) {
      const todos = todoUL.childNodes;
      todos.forEach(function(todoEl) {
        if (todoEl.nodeName === "LI") {
          switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
              todoEl.style.display = "flex";
              break;

            case "completed":
              if (todoEl.children[0].classList.contains("completed")) {
                todoEl.style.display = "flex";
              } else {
                todoEl.style.display = "none";
              }
              break;

            case "uncompleted":
              if (todoEl.children[0].classList.contains("completed")) {
                todoEl.style.display = "none";
              } else {
                todoEl.style.display = "flex";
              }
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const addTodoButton = document.getElementById('addTodoButton')
const todoUL = document.getElementById('todoUL')
const filterOptions = document.querySelector('.filter-todos')

addTodoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo)
todoUL.addEventListener('click', remove);
filterOptions.addEventListener('click', filterTodos);

// Add todo
function addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoText = input.value
    const todoEl = `<li><span>${todoText}</span> <button class="delete" id="deleteTodoButton"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>Delete</button> <button class="complete" id="completeTodoButton"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Completed</button></li>`
    input.value = ""
    input.focus()

    if (!todoText) {
        alert('You must type a todo')
    } else {
        todoUL.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", todoEl)
    }
}

// Remove/Complete todo
function remove(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'deleteTodoButton') {
        e.target.parentElement.remove()
        input.focus()
    } else {
        e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('completed')
        input.focus()
    }
}

function filterTodos(e) {
    const todos = todoUL.querySelectorAll('li > span');
    todos.forEach(function (todoEl) {
        const tgt = todoEl.parentElement;
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                tgt.style.display = "flex"
                break;

            case "completed":
                if (todoEl.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    tgt.style.display = "flex"
                } else {
                    tgt.style.display = "none"
                }
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                if (todoEl.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    tgt.style.display = "none"
                } else {
                    tgt.style.display = "flex"
                }
                break;
        }
    })
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

.completed {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <h1>Todo List App</h1>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter your todo">
      <button type="submit" class="add-todo" id="addTodoButton">Add</button>
      <select name="todos" class="filter-todos">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoUL">
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone but the list is still not being sorted.

Comment: oh, there were two questions? I see absolutely no mention of sorting in your question @Nesta

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The ultimate goal is to get the filter to work. Cheers.

Comment: filter? what does that have to do with sort?

Comment: What I meant is when you select Completed from the dropdown list to show only the completed todo items. When you select Uncompleted to show the Uncompleted ones and when select All to show all of the items.

Comment: OK ... code works now - uses different methods altogether now

Comment: I've noticed when you have for example 2 items and 1 of them is completed and then if you chose completed from the dropdown it won't sort the list however if you click on the dropdown again it does sort the items accordingly.

Comment: again  ... sort ... you mean filter ... and which browser are you using - the code works 100% in mine - oh, right ... well, your code doesn't call the filter when you hit completed button - surely you can fix that little issue yourself